# Trying to execute a scrapy FormResponse but in a vscode debug console

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I'm trying to learn how to use python scrapy and I'm wondering if I can manually request websites from the vscode debug console. Normally I would use python requests and BeautifulSoup to get website html and I would type something like

```
resp = requests.get(website)
```

directly into the debug console in vscode. From there I could make more requests to the website without restarting the debugger. However, I can't find a way to do the same thing when I'm using scrapy since the scrapy request would be yielded/returned.
Example of my request:

```
yield scrapy.Request(website, callback=self.parse_site})
```

If I try to paste `scrapy.Request(website ...)` into the vscode debug console I would get a scrapy request object, not the response that I need. I'm trying to play around with the requests without restarting the debugger every time I want to make one. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with scrapy but it should probably contain a `.reponse` attribute. Also judging by the code, your response should be inside `self.parse_site` since it's a callback. If you only want a debug mode, then make a global variable called `my response` and inside `self.parse_site` assign the return value to it. Then in debug console you can print `my_response`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html).

```
# Either type:
scrapy shell 'https://www.somewebsite.com'

# or:
scrapy shell

# and then create the request and fetch it:
req = scrapy.Request(url='https://www.somewebsite.com')
fetch(req)

# now just get whatever you want from the response, for example:
response.status
response.xpath('//div//text()')
```

To open scrapy shell in the middle of the code:

```
def parse_func(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

Comment: Alright, I see that - is there a way to use the fetch within the debug console (and not the shell)? Lets say I wanted to do `scrapy.FormRequest(site, formdata=data)` but the formdata has variables that are only avalable at runtime (viewstate - viewstategenerator). With the shell I would probably have to run through the website from the beginning manually, but if I can stop at a certain line in the debug console and then make the request from there that would make things a bit easier.

Comment: @Mathew See edit